# Spyder IDE creates too many python background processes

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After updating from Spyder 2 to 3 when I start it I see that it creates several python background processes. This wasn't happening in Spyder 2. Is this normal? The problem is that it takes too much RAM an my laptop has only 2GB memory.

[image: image from process explorer]

Comment: Use a text editor and a proper terminal emulator and 2 gigs of ram will go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. In Spyder 3 those other processes are responsible for code completion features in the Editor.

The technical details are these: those process run three completion libraries (Jedi, Rope and and a fallback library developed by us). Spyder's Editor sends completion requests to them using a client/server architecture, and displays a completion list in case it gets a successful response of any of them.